# How can I send emails (with GMail) with PHPMailer?

Tags: php, email, windows-xp, gmail

How can I send emails (with GMail) with PHPMailer?

I downloaded PHPMailer but it seems there is no documentation for it.

There is no class.phpmailer.php file inside that package.  Where is that file ?

Would you please lead me to a solution this file issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";  
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";  
$mail->Port = 465;  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication  
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com"; // SMTP username  
$mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password
```

From: http://mediakey.dk/~cc/send-email-using-php-phpmailer-and-gmail/

Comment: hello - did u see my question ? there is no class.phpmailer.php inside the downloaded file !  it seems we should call that file before using/